# Matlab parfor uses fewer cores than the allocated number of cores

Tags: bash, matlab, parallel-processing, slurm, parfor

I'm running a parallel Matlab job on a single node of a remote [cluster](https://wiki.bwhpc.de/e/Hardware_and_Architecture_(bwForCluster_JUSTUS_2)). Each node of the cluster has 2 processors with 24 cores each, for a total of 48 cores per node. The job contains some sequential code followed by a single `parfor` loop. I run it using a `slurm` bash script.

The bash script `test.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
########## Begin Slurm header ##########
#
# Give job a reasonable name
#SBATCH -J test_1
#
# Request number of nodes and CPU cores per node for job
#SBATCH --nodes=1
# Request number of tasks/process per nodes
# (determines number of workers in processed based parpool)
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=48
# Estimated wallclock time for job
#SBATCH -t 1-00
#
# Send mail when job begins, aborts and ends
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#
########### End Slurm header ##########

echo "Submit Directory:                     $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR"
echo "Working Directory:                    $PWD"
echo "Running on host                       $HOSTNAME"
echo "Job id:                               $SLURM_JOB_ID"
echo "Job name:                             $SLURM_JOB_NAME"
echo "Number of nodes allocated to job:     $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES"
echo "Number of cores allocated to job:     $SLURM_NPROCS"
echo "Number of requested tasks per node:   $SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE"

# Load module
module load math/matlab/R2020a

#   Create a local working directory on scratch
mkdir -p $SCRATCH/$SLURM_JOB_ID

# Start a Matlab program
matlab -nodisplay -batch test_1 > test_1.out 2>&1

# Cleanup local working directory
rm -rf $SCRATCH/$SLURM_JOB_ID

exit
```

The Matlab script is

```
% Create parallel pool

pc = parcluster('local');

pc.JobStorageLocation = strcat(getenv('SCRATCH'),'/',getenv('SLURM_JOB_ID'));
 
num_workers = str2double(getenv('SLURM_NPROCS'));
parpool(pc,num_workers);

% Body of the script

% Choose deterministic parameters

free_points = 845000;
pulse_points = 1300000;
dt = 2e-11;

num_freqs = 200;
freqs = linspace(-1,1,200);

rhoi = rand(72);
rhoi = rhoi + rhoi';
rhoi = rhoi/trace(rhoi);

% Iterate over random parameters

num_pars = 5;
res = zeros(num_pars,num_freqs);
for n=1:num_pars

    disp('=====');
    disp(['N = ',num2str(n)]);
    disp('=====');

    timer = tic;

    % Random parameters

    H = rand(size(rhoi));
    H = (H + H')/2;

    L1 = rand(size(rhoi));
    L2 = rand(size(rhoi));
    L3 = rand(size(rhoi));
    L4 = rand(size(rhoi));
    L5 = rand(size(rhoi));

    % Equation to solve

    ME = @(rhot, t, w)  -1i*w*(H*rhot - rhot*H) + (L1*rhot*L1' - (1/2)*rhot*L1'*L1 - (1/2)*L1'*L1*rhot) ...
                                                + (L2*rhot*L2' - (1/2)*rhot*L2'*L2 - (1/2)*L2'*L2*rhot) ...
                                                + (L3*rhot*L3' - (1/2)*rhot*L3'*L3 - (1/2)*L3'*L3*rhot) ...
                                                + (L4*rhot*L4' - (1/2)*rhot*L4'*L4 - (1/2)*L4'*L4*rhot) ...
                                                + (L5*rhot*L5' - (1/2)*rhot*L5'*L5 - (1/2)*L5'*L5*rhot);

    % Solve equation

    % IF I CHANGE TO 'for j = 1:1', ALL WORKERS ARE USED!!! MEMORY?
    for j = 1:free_points
       rhoi =  RK4(@(rho, t) ME(rho, t, 0), rhoi, j, dt);
    end

    t = toc(timer);
    disp(['Mid duration ',num2str(t),'s']);

    parfor k=1:num_freqs
        w = freqs(k);
        
        rhop = rhoi;
        
        for j=1:pulse_points
            rhop = RK4(@(rho, t) ME(rho, t, w), rhop, j, dt);
        end
        
        for j=1:free_points
            rhop = RK4(@(rho, t) ME(rho, t, 0), rhop, j, dt);
        end

        occ(k) = rhop(1,1);
    end

    % Store result

    res(n,:) = occ;

end

save('res','res');

% Delete the parallel pool

delete(gcp('nocreate'));


% Local functions

function [rho] = RK4(F, rho, k, h)

k1 = F(rho, k*h);
k2 = F(rho+h*k1/2, (k+1/2)*h);
k3 = F(rho+h*k2/2, (k+1/2)*h);
k4 = F(rho+h*k3, (k+1)*h);

rho = rho+(1/6)*h*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);

end
```

The `slurm` output is

```
#
# SOME PERSONAL INFO HERE...
#
Number of nodes allocated to job:     1
Number of cores allocated to job:     48
Number of requested tasks per node:   48
 IMPORTANT: The MATLAB Academic site license is available to employees and
 enrolled students of the the universities of (CENSORED).
 The license is available for teaching or research only.
 Commercial applications are not permitted.
```

and the Matlab output is

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 48).
=====
N = 1
=====
Mid duration 3608.9535s
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 12).

#
# REST OF OUTPUT HERE...
#
```

You see that when the Matlab script starts, a pool of 48 workers is created. But then as the `parfor` loop finally starts, `parpool` restarts and the number of workers gets downgraded to 12.

I noticed that **this only happens if the size of the loops is sufficiently large, even the non-`parfor` loops**. For instance, if I change the size of the first `for` loop to 1, then `parpool` does not restart. So I think it may have to do with memory usage somehow...?

Any idea what is happening and how I can get Matlab to use all 48 cores that were allocated?

EDIT: Another thing I've tried is to remove the `parpool` command and specify the cluster in the `parfor` loop as `parfor (k=1:num_freqs,pc)`. When I do this Matlab uses one fourth of the workers no matter the size of my loop. I'll just try to contact the admins directly...

Comment: Why is the parallel pool started twice? Where is the other `parpool` command? Does the content of the `parfor` loop maybe call another function that tries to run in parallel? Please read [mre].

Comment: That's precisely the problem. The parpool command automatically runs again when parfor is called, as if Matlab had changed its mind about the number of workers when it starts the parfor. I'll try making a minimal example tomorrow if I can, but I don't want to show the code I used because I don't own it, it was just lent to me.

Comment: To be clear, there is only one explicit call to parpool, but parfor seems to implicitly call it again for a reason I don't understand. And no, there is no other function that tries running in parallel in the parfor loop.

Comment: Ok, I changed the original post so that it has a working example. I'm starting to think it has to do with memory. When I cut the size of one of the (non-parallel) loops, `parpool` doesn't randomly restart anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m baffled, I don’t understand why this is happening. Maybe something to ask MATLAB support about. You should be able to get in touch through the people administering the license for your university.

Comment: I also notice that you have an hour of computation before you start the parallel loop. Why not make the outer loop parallel?

Comment: I'm not sure I can make the outer loop parallel because the iteration order is important: it's solving a linear ODE. In other words I am not iterating on a so-called 'reduction variable'.

Yeah I think I'll move this question to Mathworks Answers when I have a chance. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: MATLAB Answers is not customer support, it is more or less the same thing as this. You want to contact support: https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html?s_tid=hp_ff_s_support

Comment: Yeah I will also contact support also, but usually on Matlab Answers there are people who work for Mathworks and are more familiar with Matlab issues. I'll do both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet your parallel pool is timing-out in between your `parfor` loops. It then gets auto-created with size 12, as that is the default preference for "preferred number of workers in a parallel pool" ([doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel-preferences.html)). (Personally, I don't much care for that preference, and always set the value to 99999 and let other things control the size of the pool, but in your case you might not be able to if your SLURM workers don't share a MATLAB preferences directory (`prefdir`) with your client).

I suggest you create your pool of size 48 with an `IdleTimeout` of `Inf`, like this:

```
num_workers = str2double(getenv('SLURM_NPROCS'));
parpool(pc,num_workers,'IdleTimeout',Inf);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Though normally Matlab displays a message when the idle limit is reached. But it might not in R2020a. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.